# a moving tab in android application

Tags: android, mobile

I want to make a moving list appear from the left of the screen of the activity in the android app.

Something like the facebook app shown below :

[image: facebook app in android]

,,

how can I make something like that in an  android app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very popular UI pattern called a sliding menu / slider. You can search for open source libraries / projects which implement this for you.

Here is the [first one](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) I found on google.

[This one](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/tree/master/addons/slider) is useful if you want to support old (pre holo) android devices too. It's an addon to the excellent holoeverywhere library.

And last but not least, take a look at [this official pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) by google which also implements the same behavior. The code for creating it is available [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind this is that you are taking a screen grab of the current activity and then loading in the menu. Your not actually sliding between activities, your moving the screen shot. Thats a very basic explanation of whats happening.

If you search for slide navigation on github I'm sure you'll find something.